# .net Web Project using IIS authentication across untrusted domains

Tags: .net, windows, iis, windowsdomainaccount

In intranet  the website is deployed to domain A, the users are in domain B,
the 2 domains donnot trust each other. how to configure to make that the user in
Domain B can access the website in Domain A using the NT account. thanks!